# How to use ionic call-number plugin in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to dial a phone number from my **VueJs** project using **Capacitor**.

I am trying this plugin, I enabled the ionic framework on my VueJs project successfully.

I am following this tutorial https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number but it is not working for me.

I am using like this

```
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';
```

I created a method to call the function

```
async callNow() {
      CallNumber.callNumber("18001010101", true);
    },
```

But I am getting below error.
[image]

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. **this can only run on device**
2. make sure you have properly installed all libraries using npm, see `package.json` from project below
3. here is an example project where the plugin works - https://github.com/aaronksaunders/capacitor-vue-ionicv4-app/blob/master/src/components/GeolocationPage.vue

```
npm install call-number
npm install @ionic-native/call-number
npm install @ionic-native/core
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I tried the code provided by you but getting the exact same error as shown in the screenshot of my question.

Comment: I tried on the device and it is showing a blank screen due to javascript script error.

Comment: I tried further debugging, Injectable is not defined in   CallNumber.decorators = [
        { type: Injectable },
    ];  in node_modules/@ionic-native/call-number/index.js:85

Comment: i don't know what you are doing, but if you check out my project and run it, it works... that i why i posted the link, so I suggest you run MY project and see what the difference is instead of copying code. - also please show me the error in the native IDE, not the browser

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install call-number
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/call-number
ionic cap sync

import { CallNumber } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/call-number';

async call() { await CallNumber.callNumber("NUMBER", true); }
```